# i can't add Buttons in a footer

Tags: button, ionic-framework, footer

i'm trying to add buttons in a footer bar. but i get a blank footer (without buttons) 
can anyone help me please.

my code:

```
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-color-active-positive">

    <div class="button-bar">
      <button ng-repeat="button in buttons" class="button icon ion-{{button.icon}}" ng-class="{'active': activeButton == $index}" ng-click="setActiveButton($index)"> {{button.text}}</button>
    </div>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

Comment: @DaniSpringer.com idon't think that's a css error. here is my css code:          .bar-color-active-positive {
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}

Comment: Of course it's a problem. You are giving the css and the html two different classes. They gotta be one and the same.

Comment: And what's that button tag? Never saw it before. Can't you add the right class to the div itself? Later I'll post some code.

Comment: And what's the css for button-bar?

Comment: You gotta include the css for every class defined in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Through your code here, I can not locate your error, maybe you could debug your page by `Chrome Dev Tools` and add some log here.
And I have create a [plunker project](https://plnkr.co/edit/WaFeJGBeELi3kthKULFc?p=preview) about add buttons to `ion-footer-bar`, hope this will help you. Regards!

Comment: i debuged it by chrome and nothing shown (no errors) and i added the same code that you create in 'plunker' and doesn't work also. Still the same blank footer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (btw before completing this answer I need you to add the css for every class you have up here):
**HTML:**

```
<div class="button-bar">
  <button ng-repeat="button in buttons" class="button icon ion-{{button.icon}}" ng-class="{'active': activeButton == $index}" ng-click="setActiveButton($index)"> {{button.text}}</button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**